# Google Chrome extension to read omnibox imput and make a XMLHttpRequest based on it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, address-bar

Say a user types in "testing" in the omnibox. I need an extension to make a page request to http://mywebsite.com?url=testing. I can't use the keyword recognition thing, because this must work for ANY word. Any idea where to start?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to listen on omnibox key inputs unless you register a keyword, explained here http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/omnibox.html

An alternative way, would be to use the experimental [WebRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html), you can listen before every request made and do some logic that you require per URL.

For example, firing an XHR request on every request:

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', 'http://mywebsite/audit?url=' + details.url, true);
   xhr.send();
});
```

Note that this is experimental, therefore the API is not stable yet and may change in the future.

Comment: Seems like webRequest isn't experimental anymore. And the signature changed. Here is the current syntax: `var callback = function(details) {
    console.log(details);
};
var filter = {urls: ["<all_urls>"]};
var opt_extraInfoSpec = [];
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec);`